# PHP file_get_contents does not really determine if file is present

Tags: php

I'm trying to use file_get_contents to test if a .jpg exists in a directory and if so display it else just stop the loop.

This appears to work great EXCEPT when the .jpg is not in the directory it continues to look and display missing thumbnails up to 10 images.

Is there something else besides file_get_contents?  I've tried to use absolute path as well with the same results.

```
<?
$image = "<br>";
$ListingRid = $row['MLS_NUMBER'];
$img_cnt = 1;
for ($c=1;$c<11;$c++) {
    if ($c<10)
        $c_ext = "".$c;
    else
        $c_ext = $c;

    if (file_get_contents("http://mydomain.com/images/{$ListingRid}_{$c_ext}.jpg"))
        $image .= "<img src=http://mydomain.com/images/{$ListingRid}_{$c_ext}.jpg alt='' width='100' height='75' border='0' />";
    else
        $c=12;

    $img_cnt++;
    if ($img_cnt == 3) {
        $image .= "<br>";
        $img_cnt = 0;
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: $c_ext = "".$c; what does this do?

Comment: its is the value for the jpg..example:  xxxxx_6.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check to see if a file exists over HTTP by using cURL. Also, by using the CURLOPT_NOBODY option, you can check for a file's existence **without actually having to download the content**:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://mydomain.com/images/{$ListingRid}_{$c_ext}.jpg");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_exec($ch);
$retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($retcode);
```

In your case:

```
<?php

$image = "<br>";
$ListingRid = $row['MLS_NUMBER'];
$img_cnt = 1;
for ($c=1;$c<11;$c++) {
    if ($c<10)
        $c_ext = "".$c;
    else
        $c_ext = $c;


    $ch = curl_init("http://mydomain.com/images/{$ListingRid}_{$c_ext}.jpg");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($retcode == '200')
        $image .= "<img src=http://mydomain.com/images/{$ListingRid}_{$c_ext}.jpg alt='' width='100' height='75' border='0' />";
    else
        $c=12;

    $img_cnt++;
    if ($img_cnt == 3) {
        $image .= "<br>";
        $img_cnt = 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Wayne, I have to do CURL b/c I have to test in a http wrapper...any chance you could update my sample code so I can learn how to utilize your CURL sample?  I'm having trouble figuring out how to work it in?

Comment: I updated my answer. Should work, although I haven't tested it.

Comment: Totally worked, thanks so much...I'm off to go read more about CURL...thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

PHP has file_exists.

> bool `file_exists` ( string `$filename` )
>   Checks whether a file or directory exists.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: But he's using `http` wrapper to test the file. This will return false on everything.

Comment: Oh.  Then I'd go with cURL, as @Wayne Whitty suggests.

Comment: Yes, and I'm in a shared environment where this won't work:

(file_exists("/var/web/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/images/{$ListingRid}_{$c_ext}.jpg"))

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a handy function called [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) which returns a bool.